# VBA - How do I specify the Inbox instead of using my inbox?

Tags: excel, vba, database, email, lotus-notes

In my excel spreadsheet I have column A and column B. In column A I have email addresses, in column B I have unique variables. The code below is designed to look into an inbox, compare if any of the subject lines match the unique variable in column B and if they do then forward the email to the email address from column A of that unique variable. This is the code currently:

```
Public Sub Forward_Email(findSubjectLike As String, forwardToEmailAddresses As String)

    Dim NSession As Object
    Dim NMailDb As Object
    Dim NViewObj As Object
    Dim NInboxView As Object
    Dim NDocument As Object
    Dim NUIWorkspace As Object
    Dim NUIDocument As Object
    Dim NFwdUIDocument As Object
   
    
    Set NSession = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
    Call NSession.Initialize("password")
    
    Set NUIWorkspace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
    Set NMailDb = NSession.GetDatabase("", "TEST.nsf")
    Set NViewObj = NMailDb.GetView("Inbox")
    Set NDocument = Find_Document(NInboxView, findSubjectLike)
   
    If Not NDocument Is Nothing Then
   

       
        Set NUIDocument = NUIWorkspace.EditDocument(False, NDocument)
       
      
       
        NUIDocument.Forward
       
   
       
        Set NFwdUIDocument = NUIWorkspace.CurrentDocument
        Sleep 100
       
       
        NFwdUIDocument.GoToField "To"
        Sleep 100
        NFwdUIDocument.InsertText forwardToEmailAddresses
       
     
       
        NFwdUIDocument.GoToField "Body"
        NFwdUIDocument.InsertText "This email was forwarded at " & Now
        NFwdUIDocument.InsertText vbLf

        
       
        NFwdUIDocument.Send
        NFwdUIDocument.Close

       
        Do
            Set NUIDocument = NUIWorkspace.CurrentDocument
            Sleep 100
            DoEvents
        Loop While NUIDocument Is Nothing
        NUIDocument.Close
       
    Else
   
        MsgBox vbCrLf & findSubjectLike & vbCrLf & "not found in Inbox"

    End If
   
    Set NUIDocument = Nothing
    Set NFwdUIDocument = Nothing
    Set NDocument = Nothing
    Set NMailDb = Nothing
    Set NUIWorkspace = Nothing
    Set NSession = Nothing
   
End Sub

Private Function Find_Document(NView As Object, findSubjectLike As String) As Object

    Dim NThisDoc As Object
    Dim thisSubject As String
   
    Set Find_Document = Nothing
   
    Set NThisDoc = NView.GetFirstDocument
    While Not NThisDoc Is Nothing And Find_Document Is Nothing
        thisSubject = NThisDoc.GetItemValue("Subject")(0)
        If LCase(thisSubject) = LCase(findSubjectLike) Then Set Find_Document = NThisDoc
        Set NThisDoc = NView.GetNextDocument(NThisDoc)
    Wend

End Function
```

The issue is that now the code looks within the user inbox of the logged in user (in this case being me). I have another inbox open (lets call it TEST) am I able to specify this code to view the information from the open TEST inbox instead. Right now it compares the information from my inbox with TEST as it triggers the error line "not found in inbox".

What it does currently is it looks for the unique variable within my finds it, then tries to compare with TEST for that subject line to forward it. I want it to both look in TEST and then compare with TEST.

Answer (score 0):

You state "The issue is that now the code looks within the user inbox of the logged in use".  It doesn't.  It uses  NSession.CurrentDatabase,, and your NotesSession is loaded into VBA using the Notes OLE classes.  It's the OLE classes becuase you are using Notes.NotesSession instead of Lotus.NotesSesion. In the COM classes, that are loaded if you use Lotus.NotesSession., the CurrentDatabase property isn't defined. In the OLE classes, I honestly don't know what the expected behavior is in the OLE classes, but I know for sure that you can't rely on the current database always being the current user's mailbox database.

In any case, if you want to access another user's Inbox, first you have to open that user's mailbox database. To do that, you have to know what server that mailbox database is on, and what the path to the mailbox is on that server. You do that by writing code to read that information from that user's Person document in the Domino Directory, or you can put that information into your spreadsheet for each user. With that, you can use NotesSession.GetDatabase, open the database, and access it more or less the way you are accessing your own mailbox database.

Comment: I have adjusted my code and made sure to input the correct .nsf file name but I'm getting 'Object variable or With block variable not set'  at the `For Each NViewObj In NMailDb.Views` line. Using Lotus.NotesSession requests for my session to be initialized.

Comment: I have used Lotus.NotesSession and initialized it however as I try to get my Inbox view it now states Database has not been opened yet. Is this due to insufficient privileges?

Comment: It could be an access control issue. Can you open yoir TEST. NSF database from the Notes client using the same Notes ID that you are using when you run this code?